# jQuery: My click-event-method function is being entered only for some buttons, although they all have the exact same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a few forms rendered from a Django modelFormset. For each form I create an "Insert" button next to it to add a new form after it. When I load the page, the forms are rendered from the database rows, then I click on any insert button and my new form is added. Now, when I click on the insert button that's next to that newly created form, nothing happens, the function inside my click-event method is not even entered. These buttons have all the same class.

I'm creating the new form by cloning the div element that contains it, then changing its attributes, and then inserting it.

Here's what my template looks like before adding a new form. I only have two rows in my database table right now, the ones I created manually for testing.

```html
<body>
    <form method="POST" class="note-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" ...>
        <div class="notes-pane">
            <div id="management-form">...<div>
            </div>
            <div class="note" id="id-note-1">
                <input type="number" name="form-0-note_number" value="1" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="id_form-0-note_number">
                <textarea name="form-0-note_text" cols="100" rows="8" id="id_form-0-note_text">This is the first note</textarea>
                <button id="ins-after-1" class="ins-note-after" type="button" value="ins-after-1">Insert</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="60" id="id_form-0-id">
            </div>
            <div class="note" id="id-note-2">
                <input type="number" name="form-1-note_number" value="2" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="id_form-1-note_number">
                <textarea name="form-1-note_text" cols="100" rows="8" id="id_form-1-note_text">This is the second note</textarea>
                <button id="ins-after-2" class="ins-note-after" type="button" value="ins-after-2">Insert</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="form-1-id" value="61" id="id_form-1-id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript to add the buttons to the form and create the new forms.
It's probably not very clean. I'm still a beginner with JavaScript.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //--------------------ADDING INSERT-NOTE BUTTONS--------------------
        var noteFormList = $(".note").find("textarea");

        for (noteElement of noteFormList) {
            var buttonNumber = Number(noteElement.id.match(/\d+/))+1
            var newButton = $("<button></button>").text("Insert");
            newButton.attr("id", "ins-after-"+buttonNumber);
            newButton.attr("class", "ins-note-after");
            newButton.attr("type", "button");
            newButton.attr("value", "ins-after-"+buttonNumber);
            $("#"+noteElement.id).after(newButton);
            
        }

        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------------------INSERTING A NEW NOTE------------------------

        $(".ins-note-after").click(function() {
            var insertAfter = $(this).attr("value").match(/\d+/)[0];
            // To see if the function is entered.
            console.log(insertAfter);
            console.log("Inserting note after "+insertAfter);
            
            // Update the total and initial forms in the management form.
            var newTotalForms = $("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").attr("value");
            newTotalForms++;
            $("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS").attr("value", newTotalForms);
            $("#id_form-INITIAL_FORMS").attr("value", newTotalForms);

            // Getting the list of notes that need to be moved.
            // They're not moved, actually, only their indexes/numbers are changed.
            var notesToMove = $(".note").filter(function() {
                return this.id.match(/\d+/) > insertAfter
            });
            var newNote;
            var noteNumberToMod;
            var textareaToMod;
            var buttonToMod;
            var idToMod;

            // This is executed when the note will be inserted between notes.
            if (notesToMove.length > 0) {

                // Clone the first note that will be moved.
                // The insertion will be made from this one.
                newNote = $(notesToMove[0]).clone();
                newNote.find("textarea").text("");
                // Insert the new note form where it corresponds.
                $("#id-note-"+insertAfter).after(newNote);
                var changeIndex = Number(insertAfter);
                
                // Modify the attributes of every single note form
                // after the inserted one.
                for (note of notesToMove) {
                    note.id = "id-note-"+(changeIndex+2);
                    noteNumberToMod = $(note).find("#id_form-"+changeIndex+"-note_number");
                    textareaToMod = $(note).find("#id_form-"+changeIndex+"-note_text");
                    buttonToMod = $(note).find("#ins-after-"+(changeIndex+1));
                    idToMod = $(note).find("#id_form-"+changeIndex+"-id");

                    noteNumberToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-note_number");
                    noteNumberToMod.attr("value", (changeIndex+2));
                    noteNumberToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-note_number");
                    textareaToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-note_text");
                    textareaToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-note_text");
                    buttonToMod.attr("id", "ins-after-"+(changeIndex+2));
                    buttonToMod.attr("value", "ins-after-"+(changeIndex+2));
                    idToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-id");
                    idToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(changeIndex+1)+"-id");
                    idToMod.attr("value", "");

                    changeIndex++;


                }
            // This is executed when the insertion is after the last note.
            } else {
                var insAfter = Number(insertAfter);
                newNote = $("#id-note-"+insAfter).clone();
                insAfter--;
                noteNumberToMod = newNote.find("#id_form-"+insAfter+"-note_number");
                textareaToMod = newNote.find("#id_form-"+insAfter+"-note_text");
                buttonToMod = newNote.find("#ins-after-"+(insAfter+1));
                idToMod = newNote.find("#id_form-"+insAfter+"-id");

                newNote.attr("id", "id-note-"+(insAfter+2));
                noteNumberToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-note_number");
                noteNumberToMod.attr("value", (insAfter+2));
                noteNumberToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-note_number");
                textareaToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-note_text");
                textareaToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-note_text");
                buttonToMod.attr("id", "ins-after-"+(insAfter+2));
                buttonToMod.attr("value", "ins-after-"+(insAfter+2));
                idToMod.attr("name", "form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-id");
                idToMod.attr("id", "id_form-"+(insAfter+1)+"-id");
                idToMod.attr("value", "");
                newNote.find("textarea").text("");

                $("#id-note-"+(insAfter+1)).after(newNote);

            }
    }
</script>
```

After clicking on any of those two buttons, a new form is added properly. Like this:
(Please see the comments)

```html
<body>
    <form method="POST" class="note-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" ...>
        <div class="notes-pane">
            <div id="management-form">...<div>
            </div>
            <div class="note" id="id-note-1">
                <input type="number" name="form-0-note_number" value="1" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="id_form-0-note_number">
                <textarea name="form-0-note_text" cols="100" rows="8" id="id_form-0-note_text">This is the first note</textarea>
                <button id="ins-after-1" class="ins-note-after" type="button" value="ins-after-1">Insert</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="60" id="id_form-0-id">
            </div>
            <div class="note" id="id-note-2">
                <input type="number" name="form-1-note_number" value="2" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="id_form-1-note_number">
                <!-- The textarea is empty because this is the new note that was added, after the first one-->
                <textarea name="form-1-note_text" cols="100" rows="8" id="id_form-1-note_text"></textarea>
                <button id="ins-after-2" class="ins-note-after" type="button" value="ins-after-2">Insert</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="form-1-id" value="61" id="id_form-1-id">
            </div>
            <div class="note" id="id-note-3">
                <input type="number" name="form-2-note_number" value="3" class="disabled" readonly="readonly" id="id_form-2-note_number">
                <!-- This one says "This is the second note" because it was moved after inserting one before it-->
                <textarea name="form-2-note_text" cols="100" rows="8" id="id_form-2-note_text">This is the second note</textarea>
                <button id="ins-after-3" class="ins-note-after" type="button" value="ins-after-3">Insert</button>
                <!-- Don't mind this line. I still don't know how to handle it's value-->
                <input type="hidden" name="form-2-id" value id="id_form-2-id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I can click the insert button at the first note again and another new note will be added after it, or at the last note, and a new note will be added after it too. The problem is when clicking the buttons of the notes that were added with this code. Nothing happens, the function is not entered. I'm making sure their class is exactly the same, but still, the function is not even entered.

Comment: change `$(".ins-note-after").click(function() {` to `$(document).on('click', '.ins-not-after', () => {`

Comment: @fedesc Fat arrow function recommendation is `never` ideal to be used in jQuery. Since it will not recognize `$(this)`  and OP will be posting another question on that!

Comment: Right. Power of habit :D ... Just wanted to point out the change on the click event. you are right -> `$(document).on('click', '.ins-not-after', function () {`

Comment: @fedesc Great. That works. I'm reading about the difference between using `$().click()` and `$().on(click, ...)` and it's clear now that the former won't work for dynamically created elements. But aren't the first two buttons also created dynamically? They didn't exist when the page first loaded.

Comment: @TheSprinter In your 1st code-block you start with two buttons. `id="ins-after-1"` `id="ins-after-2"`

Comment: Yes, but those are added with JavaScript after the page loads. I intended those two HTML blocks to show what it looks like before and after creating a new form but, originally, the page loads without those two buttons. The first part of my JavaScript block is the one that adds them.